# How do I open (twice) file created with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I create temporary file using `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`  with some csv data to load it into mysql database. I put `time.sleep(100)` to have time for manualy check if file exist and this file exist and have proper data (I check it with my favorit text editor), but when I use this file in MySQL query then I have error `file not found`

```py
db = MyDBConnect()
cur = db.cursor()
csvfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
with csvfile as f:
    f.write("\n".join(results).encode('utf-8'))
    sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + csvfile.name + "' INTO TABLE MyResults FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
    cur.execute(sql)
    time.sleep(100)​
```

full error message:

```py
Exception _mysql_exceptions.InternalError: (2, "File '/tmp/tmpQtHxe6' not found (Errcode: 2)") in <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x7f9e3fcef4d0>> ignored​
```

I found something strange for me. It's looks like program doesn't wait for `cur.execute(sql)` if I create temp file with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)` then I have no error, but If I try delete file with `os.remove()` after `cur.execute(sql)` then I again have this error

Comment: have you checked that the db query is executed before `with csvfile`-statement is ended e.g., `with db: db.execute(sql)`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian This query need less then 1 sec to execute, then yes, I think that it shouldbe executed before `with` was ended

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian It's look like I was wrong and query isn't executed before file close/delete

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html):

> Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later). If delete is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed.

I am not overly familiar with mysql but I imagine you should maybe be passing the file object `f` after a `f.seek(0)` not trying to open again using `.name`.

Comment: probably I can't because  `LOAD DATA INFILE` takes only file_name, maybe I should create this file and delete them by myself instead of using tempfile module